# php code to break content in doc file if there is no sufficiend space for complete content block

Tags: php, doc

I am writing a doc file with number of tables but some of the tables are breaking because of not sufficient space in that doc page.

So is there any method by which we can find the remaining page length while writing a doc file with php?

Comment: You mean a .doc file, as in MS Word? Could help if you can post some details about which libraries you use, or even a *short* code snippet showing what already works for you - more chances you'd get an answer if you do.

Comment: Yes, it is a word file. I have a page on my site where I am having all the clients details in different tables, so as data is too much there and I want that data to be exported in .doc file, it is taking 8-10 pages is .doc file but some of data are breaking like for a client detail table half of the table is coming in one page  and another half is coming in next page. This situation I want to avoid here. So if there is not sufficient space  in doc page for complete one table then that complete table should be shifted to next doc page. Hope this information helps.

Answer (score 0):

please share some code that what you have implement to execute the code and libraries what are including to resolve this issue. One thing can be arise in that your code is assuming only one page in doc file and reading character by character